# How to reduce the size of an mpeg file using the command line ?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, file-format

I have a file, the output of the file command displays:

```
jeff_western2.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 1
```

I do not know how to lookup the resolution but it looks quiet high, the file itself is about 37 MB big.

I need to keep that file as a mpeg file or another format which is capable to be displayed on a smartphone, but to have its size reduced, whether by lowering the resolution or another way.

Answer (score 2):

install the best video tool on planet, ffmpeg (ffprobe, ffplay and ffmpeg are inside)

find out everything about file:

```
ffprobe filename.mp4
```

converting mp4 with standard options:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -strict -2 file2.mp4
```

...will probably reduce the size itself, but if not, try adding option '-b:v 300K' just before 'file2.mp4' in above command, to limit video bitrate.